# eshop XML transformations needed

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi guys I have this following XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products siteID="629">
  <product id="14321904">
    <name>Taior, negru</name>
    <description3>
      <ul>
        <li>articol de damă</li>
        <li>decolteu în V</li>
        <li>inserţii din piele eco</li>
        <li>închidere cu un singur nasture</li>
        <li>material: decolteu în V</li>
        <li>inserţii din piele eco</li>
        <li>închidere cu un singur nasture</li>
      </ul>
    </description3>
    <material>100% poliester</material>
    <ModelSizingDescr/>
    <Measurements/>
    <SupplierColor/>
  </product>
  <product id="14321905">
    <name>Taior, negru</name>
    <description3>
      <ul>
        <li>articol de damă</li>
        <li>decolteu în V</li>
        <li>inserţii din piele eco</li>
        <li>închidere cu un singur nasture</li>
        <li>material: decolteu în V</li>
        <li>inserţii din piele eco</li>
        <li>închidere cu un singur nasture</li>
      </ul>
    </description3>
    <material>100% poliester</material>
    <ModelSizingDescr/>
    <Measurements/>
    <SupplierColor/>
  </product>
```

I'm a bit rusty with XSLT and haven't managed to do much. What I want is to get rid of the duplicate text in the `<li>` tags (which I managed to do to a certain extent). Secondly I want to replace this line `<li>material: decolteu în V</li>` with the content from the  node further down so it looks like this `<li>material: 100% poliester</li>`. To wrap it up the processed XML file should look like this:

```html
<products siteID="629">
  <product id="14321904">
    <name>Taior, negru</name>
    <description3>
      <ul>
        <li>articol de damă</li>
        <li>decolteu în V</li>
        <li>inserţii din piele eco</li>
        <li>închidere cu un singur nasture</li>
        <li>material: 100% poliester</li>
      </ul>
    </description3>
    <material>100% poliester</material>
    <ModelSizingDescr/>
    <Measurements/>
    <SupplierColor/>
  </product>
```

Any ideas and suggestions welcomed, thanks in advance!

Comment: **1.** Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. -- **2.** Why are there two products in your input, but only one in your output?

Comment: 1.0 or 2.0 as long as it works. For the second example output I forgot to add the other product. Solution has been submitted DroidDP. Thanks for input Michael.

Comment: Not sure what to make of your response. If you are using a XSLT 2.0 processor, then you should take advantage of the features that are only available in XPath/XSLT 2.0, e.g. the `<xsl:for-each-group>` istruction or the `distinct-values()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0, you can do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul">
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(li)[not(starts-with(., 'material:'))]">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('material:', ../../material)"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example (after correcting it for well-formedness!), **results** in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products siteID="629">
   <product id="14321904">
      <name>Taior, negru</name>
      <description3>
         <li>articol de damă</li>
         <li>decolteu în V</li>
         <li>inserţii din piele eco</li>
         <li>închidere cu un singur nasture</li>
         <li>material:100% poliester</li>
      </description3>
      <material>100% poliester</material>
      <ModelSizingDescr/>
      <Measurements/>
      <SupplierColor/>
   </product>
   <product id="14321905">
      <name>Taior, negru</name>
      <description3>
         <li>articol de damă</li>
         <li>decolteu în V</li>
         <li>inserţii din piele eco</li>
         <li>închidere cu un singur nasture</li>
         <li>material:100% poliester</li>
      </description3>
      <material>100% poliester</material>
      <ModelSizingDescr/>
      <Measurements/>
      <SupplierColor/>
   </product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need two products in the output. and xsl v1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li">
        <xsl:if test="not(node()) or not(preceding-sibling::node()[.=string(current())])">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li/text()[.='material: decolteu în V']">material: 100% poliester</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input the response would be

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products siteID="629">
    <product id="14321904">
        <name>Taior, negru</name>
        <description3>
            <ul>
                <li>articol de damă</li>
                <li>decolteu în V</li>
                <li>inserţii din piele eco</li>
                <li>închidere cu un singur nasture</li>
                <li>material: 100% poliester</li>
            </ul>
        </description3>
        <material>100% poliester</material>
        <ModelSizingDescr/>
        <Measurements/>
        <SupplierColor/>
    </product>
    <product id="14321905">
        <name>Taior, negru</name>
        <description3>
            <ul>
                <li>articol de damă</li>
                <li>decolteu în V</li>
                <li>inserţii din piele eco</li>
                <li>închidere cu un singur nasture</li>
                <li>material: 100% poliester</li>
            </ul>
        </description3>
        <material>100% poliester</material>
        <ModelSizingDescr/>
        <Measurements/>
        <SupplierColor/>
    </product>
</products>
```

Comment: You should learn about Muenchian grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Works great DroidDP, I will study further. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question. How is this possible to be done dynamically? This line <li>material: decolteu în V</li> will vary from product to product, the only thing that is constant is the string "material: ".  The same goes inside the <material> node, it varies from product to product. I've tried doing a match with a regex with the word "material: " but to no avail...